When sending JSON data from the Flask server to Flutter, the data does not come out completely and gets cut off every time after 80-90
When sending JSON data from the Flask server to Flutter, the data does not come out completely and gets cut off every time after 80-90 characters. How can I solve this issue?
When I take a photo and send it to the Flask server, the server returns a value in JSON format, but the data gets cut off in the middle. How can I solve this issue?
 static Future<AiData> uploadImage(String imagePath) async {
    var formData = FormData.fromMap({
      'file': await MultipartFile.fromFile(imagePath),
    });

    try {
      final response = await flaskDio.post(
        '/upload',
        data: formData,
        options: Options(
          validateStatus: (status) {
            return status! < 500;
          },
        ),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // JSON 형식의 응답 데이터를 문자열로 로깅
        final responseDataString = response.data.toString();
        logger.i('Raw response data: $responseDataString');

        try {
          // 응답 데이터를 JSON으로 디코딩
          var responseData = jsonDecode(responseDataString) as Map<String, dynamic>;
          logger.i('Decoded response data: $responseData');
          return AiData.fromJson(responseData);
        } catch (e) {
          logger.e('Failed to decode JSON: $e');
          throw Exception('Failed to decode JSON: $e');
        }
      } else {
        logger.e('Image upload failed.');
        throw Exception('Failed to upload image: ${response.statusMessage}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      logger.e('Image upload failed: $e');
      if (e is DioError) {
        logger.e('Dio error message: ${e.message}');
        logger.e('Dio error response: ${e.response}');
        logger.e('Dio error response data: ${e.response?.data}');
      }
      throw Exception('Image upload failed: $e');
    }
  }


I have a sense this might rather be a truncation issue on the logging, rather than the actual output.
There is a thread about it here, where the suggested solution is to implement this custom printer that chunks the output in appropriate sizes:
void printWrapped(String text) {
  final pattern = new RegExp('.{1,800}'); // 800 is the size of each chunk
  pattern.allMatches(text).forEach((match) => print(match.group(0)));
}

Do this to confirm there is no issue with your json:
void printWrapped(String text) {
  final pattern = new RegExp('.{1,800}'); // 800 is the size of each chunk
  pattern.allMatches(text).forEach((match) => print(match.group(0)));
}

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  // JSON 형식의 응답 데이터를 문자열로 로깅
  final responseDataString = response.data.toString();
  printWrapped('Raw response data: $responseDataString');
}

